# Как указать папку для новых проектов Laravel на Windows7?

Tags: windows, laravel, composer

Установил на Windows7 Composer, потом создаю новый проект Laravel командой "laravel new blog" - и после завершения процесса папку "blog" нахожу в "c:\Users\User". Как мне поменять настройки (не знаю чьи именно - композер или ларавель), чтобы папки новых проектов создавались в нужной мне папке: "c:\My_laravel_projecs", чтобы в данном случае получилось бы "c:\My_laravel_projecs\blog"?

Comment: Так переходите туда, куда нужно и пишете laravel new ./blog

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в консоли перейти в ту папку в которой хотите чтобы создался новый проект, например:

- Win + R
- введите "cmd" - Enter
- в консоли выполнить команду "cd C:\My_laravel_projecs"
- "laravel new blog"
- тут уже проект развернется по адресу C:\My_laravel_projecs\blog\
- PROFIT!!!

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.